Vispy Application Throws FT_Exception After Packaging with PyInstaller, but Works on Other Machines
I’m working on a Python project that uses Vispy for rendering. When I run the Python script (.py), everything works perfectly. I packaged the application into an executable (.exe) using PyInstaller, and the executable works fine on other computers. However, when I run the packaged executable on my own computer, it throws an FT_Exception error.
Steps:

The Python script runs without any issues when executed directly.
After packaging the script with PyInstaller, the .exe runs correctly on other machines but fails on mine with freetype.ft_errors.FT_Exception: FT_Exception:  (cannot open resource)

# -*- mode: python -*-
# ls2.spec
import sys
from PyInstaller.compat import is_win, is_darwin, is_linux
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules,collect_dynamic_libs
import vispy.glsl
import vispy.io
import freetype

block_cipher = None

data_files = [
    (os.path.dirname(vispy.glsl.__file__), os.path.join("vispy", "glsl")),
    (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(vispy.io.__file__), "_data"), os.path.join("vispy", "io", "_data")),
    (os.path.dirname(vispy.util.__file__), os.path.join("vispy", "util")),
    (os.path.dirname(freetype.__file__), os.path.join("freetype")),
]

hidden_imports = [
    "vispy.ext._bundled.six",
    "vispy.app.backends._wx",
    "vispy.app.backends._pyqt5",
    "freetype"
]

if is_win:
    hidden_imports += collect_submodules("encodings")


a = Analysis(
    ['ls2.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=data_files,
    hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='ls2',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='ls2',
)

WARNING: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ls.py", line 229, in <module>
  File "vispy\app\backends\_qt.py", line 626, in event
  File "vispy\app\backends\_qt.py", line 626, in event
  File "vispy\app\backends\_qt.py", line 928, in paintGL
  File "vispy\util\event.py", line 453, in __call__
    self._invoke_callback(cb, event)
  File "vispy\util\event.py", line 471, in _invoke_callback
    _handle_exception(self.ignore_callback_errors,
  << caught exception here: >>
  File "vispy\util\event.py", line 469, in _invoke_callback
    cb(event)
  File "vispy\scene\canvas.py", line 219, in on_draw
  File "vispy\scene\canvas.py", line 278, in _draw_scene
  File "vispy\scene\canvas.py", line 316, in draw_visual
  File "vispy\scene\visuals.py", line 106, in draw
  File "vispy\visuals\visual.py", line 668, in draw
  File "vispy\visuals\visual.py", line 668, in draw
  File "vispy\visuals\visual.py", line 505, in draw
  File "vispy\visuals\text\text.py", line 533, in _prepare_draw
  File "vispy\visuals\text\text.py", line 534, in <listcomp>
  File "vispy\visuals\text\text.py", line 264, in _text_to_vbo
  File "vispy\visuals\text\text.py", line 81, in __getitem__
  File "vispy\visuals\text\text.py", line 95, in _load_char
  File "vispy\util\fonts\_freetype.py", line 50, in _load_glyph
    face = _load_font(f['face'], f['bold'], f['italic'])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "vispy\util\fonts\_freetype.py", line 37, in _load_font
    font = Face(fname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "freetype\__init__.py", line 1192, in __init__
    raise FT_Exception(error)
freetype.ft_errors.FT_Exception: FT_Exception:  (cannot open resource)

Why does the packaged executable work on other computers but not on mine? How can I resolve this FT_Exception error and ensure the executable runs correctly on my machine?

I am not sure if you have the same problem, but for me it was because the path to the exe contained non ASCII characters. This is why it works in most systems but crashes on others.  There is an open pull request to fix that https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py/pull/177.
Here is an easy way to reproduce; the exe worked fine until I added non ASCII characters to its parent folder. To be clear, a non-ASCII character will cause this regardless of where it is in the path (for example, if the exe is inside the user's folder and the username has non ASCII characters)


Please edit your question to include the error messages as text rather than screenshot. See here for reasons to avoid posting code and errors as screenshots.

Mhmm.. I didn't want to show the actual error message, just to show that it happens with the non ASCII characters added to the path, without actually showing the path (as it contains stuf I didn't want to include). It's the same error message as the OP, I just wanted to add visual support to my answer. I can delete the picture if that's better though :)
